# Is it possible to integrate Adsense Ads in website developed using Docusaurus?

Tags: adsense, docusaurus

I am working on a tutorials website using static site generator Docusaurus. I am wondering if is it possible to integrate Adsense Ads in website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Docusaurus is just a React app, so you can include any third party JavaScript SDK/libraries.